# Why Bubble Sort needs nested loops?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I am going to start the new question. I posed the question yesterday and wanted to know what's the problem in my program. The program is given below and you people pointed out that this following program does only one pass of the sorting and needs an outer loop as well. At that time I was good like OK. But again when I looked the program I got confused and need to ask Why we need Outer loop as well for the sort since only a single loop can do the sorting(In my opinion). First see program below then I present my logic at the end of the program.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

main()
{

    int number[10];
    int temp = 0;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Please enter any ten numbers to sort one by one: "
         << "\n";

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> number[i];
    }

    i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {

        if (number[i] > number[i + 1])
        {
            temp = number[i + 1];
            number[i + 1] = number[i];
            number[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    cout << "The sorted numbers are given below:"
         << "\n";

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << number[i] << "\n";
    }

    getch();
}
```

I think the ONLY loop with the bubble condition should do the sorting. Look at the following loop of the program:

```
for (i=0;i<9;i++)
if(number[i]>number[i+1])
{
    temp=number[i+1];
    number[i+1]=number[i];
    number[i]=temp;

}
```

Now I explain what I am thinking what this loop "should" do. It will first compare number[0] with number[1]. If the condition is satisfied it will do what is in IF statement's body. Then i will be incremented by 1(i++). Then on next iteration the values compared will be number[1] with number[2]. Then why it does not happen and the loop exits after only pass? In other words may be I'm trying to ask IF statement does not repeat itself in for loop? In my opinion it does. I'm very thankful for help and views, my question might be of small level but that is how I will progress.

Comment: It is a very basic question on sorting, i will give you a hint: put the smallest value on the last position [9]. It will be compared and moved to the previous position [8] and then your loop finishes. Sorting is just not finished yet.

Comment: Very simple and clarifying example. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let me give you an example let's only take 3 numbers. So you input

```
13, 3 ,1
```

Now you start sorting how you did it. so it compares 13 and 3
`13 > 3` so switch both of them.
now we have.

```
3, 13, 1
```

Now it'll compare as you said the next pair = 13 and 1
`13 > 1` so the new order would be

```
3, 1, 13
```

now your loop is finished and you missed to compare  3 and 1
Actually the first loop only sorts the greatest number!

Comment: I don't know from where to do this since i'm new to this website. Never mind I do it after looking where is the option to do so.

Comment: @user1643568: As an asker, you have a privilige of [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You can do it by clicking the green check (V) sign next to one of the answers. You can accept only one answer, and it should be the answer that helped YOU the most.

Comment: On the left side of my post there is a contour of a check mark. Clicking it means that you accept this post as the "best"

Comment: Hard to choose between amit's and lorenz albert's answer. Both were perfect but since lorenz asked it so I marked his answer the best. Amit's was clear and comprehensive as well.

Answer (score 11):

> since only a single loop can do the sorting(In my opinion)

This is not correct. Without getting to details, **a constant number of loops is not enough to sort**, since sorting is `Omega(nlogn)` problem. Meaning, an `O(1)` (constant, including 1) number of loops is not enough for it - for any algorithm<sup>1,2</sup>.

Consider the input

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

a single loop of bubble sort will do:

```
4, 5, 3, 2, 1
4, 3, 5, 2, 1 
4, 3, 2, 5, 1
4, 3, 2, 1, 5
```

So the algorithm will end up with the array: `[ 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]`, which is NOT sorted.

After **one loop of bubble sort, you are only guaranteed to have the last element in place** (which indeed happens in the example). The second iteration will make sure the 2 last elements are in place, and the `n`th iteration will make sure the array is indeed sorted, resulting in `n` loops, which is achieved via a nested loop.

---

(1) The outer loop is sometimes hidden as a recursive call ([quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is an example where it happens) - but there is still a loop.

(2) [Comparisons based algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), to be exact.

Comment: Thanks amit. 
Means in one loop one number is at its correct position. Repeating it n(where n=items to be sorted) will sort all n numbers. Thanks it helped me to clear ambiguity.

Comment: @user1643568: Exactly. This is what bubble sort do. It is also how we can prove it (bubble sort) work. I am glad I helped you understand better how it works.

Comment: Though the answer selected as best answer also gave the correct answer but you explained it in a more better and detailed way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For bubble sorting a pass simply moves the largest element to the end of array. So you need n-1 passes to get a sorted array, thats why you need other loop. Now for your code 1 pass means

```
if(number[0]>number[0+1])
{
    temp=number[0+1];
    number[0+1]=number[0];
    number[0]=temp;

}
if(number[1]>number[1+1])
{
    temp=number[1+1];
    number[1+1]=number[1];
    number[1]=temp;

}
.....6 more times
if(number[8]>number[8+1])
{
    temp=number[8+1];
    number[8+1]=number[8];
    number[8]=temp;

}
```

so as you can see IF statement repeats itself, its just that after all 9 IFs the largets element moves to the end of array

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct because

> The algorithm gets its name from the way **smaller elements** "bubble" to the top of the list. ([Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort))

So, at the end of the first loop, we get the **smallest element**. So, for complete sorting, we have to keep **total n loops**. (where n = total size of the numbers)